# convert a timestamp field of data type varchar to date with format "yyyyMMdd" in trino

Tags: presto, trino

> convert a timestamp field of data type varchar to date with format "yyyyMMdd" in trino

load_ts field is a varchar type and i want to filter the records updated after 20220415

```
select * from table where load_ts > '20220415'
```

> sample value load_ts : 2022-06-23 21:52:37.607
>
> i want to run the query in **trino**

Answer (score 0):

Just convert both into date/timestamp:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset (load_ts) AS (
    VALUES ('2022-06-23 21:52:37.607')
)

-- query
select *
from dataset
where cast(load_ts as timestamp) > date '2022-04-15';
```

Output:

| load_ts |
| --- |
| 2022-06-23 21:52:37.607 |